# Как вызывать метод контроллера из представления

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

В новой версии MVC убрали метод @Html.Action() как теперь вызывать методы контроллеров. 
Допустим я хочу из _Layout вызывать некий метод Menu из NavController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На смену `@Html.Action` пришли `ViewComponents`. Они работают похоже, но не точно так же как и `@Html.Action`.

Например, в `MVC5` и раньше, выполнение 'дочерних действий' также влекло за собой выполнение любых фильтров (например, если контроллер был декорирован какими-нибудь фильтрами) придавая им видимость обычных действий

Но это не так для `ViewComponents`. Они выполняются в контексте текущего запроса.

[Подробнее про `ViewComponents`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components)

<sub>перевод ответа [@KiranChalla](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26938821/2881286)</sub>